Different ways to understand fermions
I first learned about fermions in my atomic physics class, where the teacher said that electrons obey the Pauli exclusion principle. Later, in my quantum mechanics class, I learned about identical particles, where it was explained that the wavefunction of fermions acquires an additional minus sign upon exchange.
Then in group theory class, the representations of $SU(2)$ have successfully described the spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particles. In QFT, we find the spinor representation for Lorentz group to construct the Dirac euqations to describe fermions. In path intergral formalism, we use the Grassmann numbers in describing fermions.
When I listened to the lectures about frontier physics, I noticed some more interesting ways to describe fermions. For example, in supersymmetry, people introduce one more fermionic dimension in superspace, described by a chiral Weyl spinor $\theta$. And in topological physics, I have listened to a lecture that the fermions' behavior could be described by the exchange of path in the configurations space, and studied in knot theory systematically (sorry for not remembering the exact papers, but a related introduction could be found in Section 3 of Simon's Topological Quantum). I also have heard that in string-net condensation fermions are the end of open strings.
My question is:

Are there any other interesting ways to describe fermions?
How are these ways related to each other? In my opinion the different ways are all generated by the anti-commuting nature of fermions. But how is the math beneath related to each other? For instance, the way we think of knots is very different from how we think in $SU(2)$ group, let alone how we think of Fermi statistics.
Do we have dualities in those different theories? What I mean is, have we ever been inspired by a solution method from one describing theory and then generalized it to other theories?

